# Unable to load class php-ds classes in PHP 7 as I get fatal error:class not found

Tags: php, data-structures, namespaces, composer-php

I am new to PHP 7 development and I have started working with Composer and PHP. I need to use PHP 7 Data structure like Vector and Stack etc. For this I have created a composer.json in my root directory to require php DS. After composer install, it has created a folder called Vendor and the PHP ds folder is inside it.

I am using the below code in a robots.php file inside the root directory.

```
<?php
use Ds\Stack;
use Ds\Vector;

$Vector = new Vector();

$stack = new  Stack();
```

I get fatal error saying class not found.
I am not aware of how the autoloading works completely. Will I be able to call these class from  my php file in the root folder?

Comment: You need to `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Autoloading**

For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a `vendor/autoload.php` file. You can simply include this file and start using the classes that those libraries provide without any extra work:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ds\Stack;
use Ds\Vector;

$Vector = new Vector();

$stack = new  Stack();
```

I suggest you take a look at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Answer (score 0):

That's because *Php DS* is a PHP extension, you have to install it first.

```
$ apt-get install php7.4-ds
```

This might help you:

- https://adamlangley.com.au/install-php-7-3-required-php-extensions-for-wordpress-on-ubuntu-nginx/

There is also a polyfill package, this means that *Php Ds* classes will be available even if the extension is not installed, although I suppose this has some performance costs.

- https://packagist.org/packages/php-ds/php-ds